# Can I make R file path independent from packageName?

Tags: android, android-resources

For exampel my application has `com.example.app1` packageName. When importing `R` file it hase `com.example.app1.R` path. If I change packageName to `com.example.app2` it will have `com.example.app2.R` path. So it must be changed in all files (Eclipse does it atomatically) but I don't want to do it. So can I have path to `R` file independent from packageName?

Comment: No you cannot. Have you ever heard about [**refactoring**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_refactoring)? Such simple renaming takes like 2 seconds if you refactor properly.

Comment: Eclipse automatically does it if you change packageName through it using Android Tools option in project drop down menu (which I mentioned in question). So answering "no" would be enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't do that.

`R` is generated at compile time by the Android development platform as a class (and a collection of inner classes) belonging to the package `your.app.package.name`. As of today (API 20), no user preference or setting allows changing the way it is generated.

Answer (score 0):

> Can I make R file path independent from packageName? **NO**

Eclipse will immediately generate the resource file R.java related to your package name, if it changes the imports must chage since R.java file have all the resources IDs provided to resources related to your package.